# Efficiently getting bits of N! ?

Tags: algorithms, co.combinatorics, nt.number-theory, computational-complexity

Given $N$ and $M$, is it possible to get the $M$'th bit (or digit of any small base) of $N!$ in time/space of $O( p( ln(N), ln(M) ) )$, where $p(x, y)$ is some polynomial function in $x$ and $y$?

i.e. Given $N = 2^\eta$, $M = 2^\mu$ (with $N$, $M \in \mathbb{Z}$), find bit $2^\mu$ of $(2^\eta)!$ in $O( p(\eta, \mu) )$.

Or perhaps I should be asking whether this problem is NP-Complete?

NOTE: Crossposted to [cstheory.stackexchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2204/efficiently-getting-bits-of-n) where Suresh Venkat was kind enough to point me to Dick Lipton's [post from 2009](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/factoring-and-factorials/) that seems to indicate that this problem is as hard as factoring.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, which I believe assumes that the base n is fixed, i.e. n=O(1), but I note that if n is allowed to grow with N, say log n ~ c log N for some small constant c > 0, then the answer to your question is almost certainly no, since a positive answer would give a polynomial-time algorithm to factor n (even just using M=0).

Comment: Some trivial observations: $\eta$ and $\mu$ should be related. If $\eta > 2^\mu$ (roughly, I may be missing a constant factor), then $N!$ has bit $M$ precisely 0. If $\mu > \eta 2^\eta$ then the bit is also 0. But the relationship doesn't seem to simplify the quesiton. 

Comment: there is also a theoretical computer science stackexchange

Comment: @ohai: This site gets more traffic.  If I don't get an answer in a reasonable amount of time I will cross post.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, but I can do it polynomially in $\log N$ and $M$.  In other words, the problem isn't hard if $M$ is small.

Stirling's formula approximating $N!$ gives the first few terms of a [convergent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#A_convergent_version_of_Stirling.27s_formula) for $\log(N!)$.  Using this series, we may approximate $\log(N!)$ to any fixed degree of accuracy in polynomial time (in $\log N$).  Indeed, if you work it out, you'll see that you can approximate $\log(N!)$ within $2^{-M}$ in $O(M^2 \log N \log\log N)$ time.  (Recall $\log N \log\log N$ is the cost of multiplication with a fast Fourier transform; if you multiplied naively, it would be $(\log N)^2$.)  Approximating $\log(N!)$ within $2^{-M}$ is exactly what it takes to get the first $M$ digits.

Your question is actually equivalent to: Can you quickly pull out *any* digit of $N!$?  There are only about $N \log N$ digits, so $M$ is bounded by a polynomial in $N$.  By the above, we can get digits near the beginning.  Digits near the end will also be easy: The problem then reduces to modular arithmetic and divisibility considerations.  But I have no idea whether there's a fast way to pull out digits in the middle.

Comment: Yes, that is the question...can you efficiently get the middle bits

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is thought to be hard, but I unfortunately have no reference to give.

A "complexity class" upper bound in given by Peter Bürgisser 
in the paper [On defining integers and proving arithmetic circuit lower bounds](http://math-www.uni-paderborn.de/agpb/work/6dich.pdf).
Specifically he shows the problem is in the counting hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't understand correctly (*edit: I didn't, see below*), but isn't this a trivial problem?

The complexity of multiplication is $m(n):=O(n\lg n)$ (where $\lg:=\log_2$) for two numbers of length $n$. We can naively compute factorial recursively via the good old $$N!=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if } N=0\\\\ N\cdot(N-1)! & \text{if }N>0.\end{cases}$$ The length of $N$ in base $2$ is approximately $\lg N$, so multiplication has an upper bound of $m(\lg N)$. Clearly this terminates in $N$ steps and hence requires $N$ multiplications, and therefore has a complexity of $O(Nm(\lg N))=O(N\lg N\lg\lg N)$. Supposing looking up the $M$th digit is $O(1)$, it is then just $O(N\lg N\lg\lg N)$. If look-up is linear in length, then it's $O(N(\lg N)^2\lg\lg N)$.

*Edit: I guess I just forgot that it should be strictly polynomial in $\lg N$, which $N(\lg N)^2\lg\lg N$ of course isn't. Sorry about that. I'll refrain from deleting this though for the sake of ... completeness?*